# Atom in superposition: is it an atom-photon system, and what is the role of the environment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, energy-conservation, atoms, superposition

Let's assume an atom would get from its ground state $|g\rangle$ to its first excited state $|e\rangle$ by absorbing a single photon.

Now, let's assume the atom gets from $|g\rangle$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)$. Does this mean that it had to "steal" 1 photon from the environment? So the superposition state is really an atom-photon system, where the two basis states are:

1. Atom in $|g\rangle$ with a "free" photon.
2. Atom in $|e\rangle$, photon absorbed.

Or can the atom get from $|g\rangle$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)$ just by itself, without the "help" of its environment? I guess that would violate the law of conservation of energy.

(Philosophical sidenote: what I find confusing is that when the atom absorbs/emits a photon, it is still considered the same atom afterwards. On the other hand, I have no problem with accepting that when an atom changes its position, it remains the same atom.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible model to describe what you want is the [Jaynes-Cumming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model) interaction. It describes the interaction of a two level system (your atom) with a single electromagnetic mode.

I assume the field and atom are resonant so that the total Hamiltonian is written in the Schrodingër picture:

$$H=-\frac{\hbar \omega}{2} \sigma_z + \hbar \omega a^{\dagger} a + \frac{\hbar \Omega_0}{2}\left( a \sigma_+ + a^{\dagger} \sigma_- \right)$$

But I will consider working in the interaction picture with respect to $-\frac{\hbar \omega}{2} \sigma_z + \hbar \omega a^{\dagger} a$ to make discussion easier, in this case the Hamiltonian is more simply:

$$H_{JC}=\frac{\hbar \Omega_0}{2}\left( a \sigma_+ + a^{\dagger} \sigma_- \right)$$

Where the operator $a$ is the annihilation operator which destoys one photon in the field:

$$a|n\rangle = \sqrt{n} |n-1 \rangle$$

And $a^{\dagger}$ creates an excitation:

$$a^{\dagger}|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1} |n+1 \rangle$$

**From now on I will assume this Hamiltonian $H_{J.C}$ to describe the dynamic**. When you go into interaction picture it is equivalent to reason in the lab in a rotating frame, so you can see it as a change a frame.

Knowing the evolution of the states $|e,n\rangle$ and $|g,n\rangle$ in principle we can deduce the evolution of any initial atom state for any field state.

It is possible to show that, with $\Omega_n \equiv \Omega_0 \sqrt{n+1} $, and where I take by convention for $n<0$: $|n\rangle=0$

$$e^{-\frac{i H_{JC} t}{\hbar}}|e,n\rangle=\cos(\frac{\Omega_n t}{2}) |e,n \rangle - \sin(\frac{\Omega_n t}{2}) |g,n+1 \rangle$$

And:

$$e^{-\frac{i H_{JC} t}{\hbar}}|g,n\rangle=\sin(\frac{\Omega_{n-1} t}{2}) |e,n-1 \rangle + \cos(\frac{\Omega_{n-1} t}{2}) |g,n \rangle$$

Now, to answer your question, if you have a given **fixed** number of photons in your field, you will see that an initial atom state will **get entangled with the field**:

$$|g,n \rangle \to  \sin(\frac{\Omega_{n-1} t}{2}) |e,n-1 \rangle + \cos(\frac{\Omega_{n-1} t}{2}) |g,n \rangle    $$

Now to answer your question precisely: it is not possible to do the transformation you want with fixed photons number in the field (if by photon you mean a fock state). One physical reason why is that it would violate the measurement postulate of Q.M. Indeed it would mean that by measuring if the field absorbed or relaxed photons, you would be able to deduce what state is the atom after interaction wihout perturbing the atom. For instance here if I measure the number of photon in my field, if I find $n$, it projects my atom in $|g \rangle$. If I find $n-1$ it projects it in $|e\rangle$. The fact we do not violate measurement postulate is precisely because of the entanglement: the atom gets in a mixed state after interacting.

What you have to do to perform the transformation you want is to consider the field in a **coherent** state, i.e a field:

$$|\alpha \rangle = \sum_n c_n |n \rangle$$

With $c_n = e^{-|\alpha|^2} \alpha^n / \sqrt{n!}$

The **average** number of photon in this state is $\overline{n}=|\alpha|^2$. Calculating the evolution of: $\left(a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle \right) |\alpha\rangle$ for a time of interaction $t=\theta/(\Omega_0 \sqrt{\overline{n}})$ **in the limit** $\overline{n} \to +\infty$ it is possible to show that the final atom state obtained will correspond

$$|g,\alpha\rangle \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|g\rangle + |e \rangle) \otimes |\alpha\rangle $$

This is one of the reasons why coherent states are considered as classical states: in the limit of large photons they reproduce the expected dynamic of an electromagnetic field modelled as classical: i.e they reproduce a **classical** Rabi oscillation (the atom remains in a pure state).

And here as you see it doesn't violate the measurement postulate as the field is in the same state before and after the interaction. Note that this doesn't really violate the energy conservation because here it is what happen in a limit of $\alpha \to \infty$. For any fixed (but big) value of $\alpha$ you would still have some slight entanglement between atom and field. By measuring the number of photon in the field you would have access to information about the atom state and make it "collapse" in an analog way as before.

And the sum of the energy in the obtained field state and in the state where the atom has collapsed will correspond to the initial energy you had at the beginning (it is an analog situation as the one described with fock state).

The thing is that the more energy you put in the field and the less entanglement there will have. You have absolutely $0$ entanglement only in the theoretical infinite number of photon limit.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, my gut feeling tells me this answer is correct! (I cannot do more than that, I only read books on quantum computing so far.) So is it true in general that we basically never have pure states in reality (other than the universe itself, maybe), they are always an unattainable idealization, for every real physical system? We can only approximate certain quantum states as pure just because we don't have the technical possibility to measure the large environment precise enough? (As the number of particles is finite in any physical system we know of.)

Comment: @TamásV You are welcome. Well in practice there is necesseraly either classical noise, either some slight entanglement of your system with something else. So in practice all state are mixed in a way. But for all practical purposes many states can be considered as pure. However I am not sure to understand what you mean with "measuring the large environement"

Comment: I had in mind what you wrote, guessing that if $\alpha$ is big, in practice we may not be able to measure the number of photons accurately, that's why we can say for all practical purposes the atom's mixed state can be considered as pure. And I imagined photons as independent "billiard balls", was not aware of Fock states. So I naively thought the atom just snaps one of those balls into the atom's kind of sealed black box, and even if we measure the environment afterwards and find 1 less photon, we still cannot tell what amplitude values the atom's superposition state exactly has.

Comment: @TamásV yes this is somewhat the intuitive explanation. If $\alpha$ is big you would have fields states in which 1 more or less photon will not make a big change. Basically you have what is called a which path experiment in which the two field state of the field are almost indistinguishable. The less photon you had initially the more they become distinguishable because adding 1 photon in a coherent field having 3 photons would induce a lot of difference than adding 1 photon in a field containing thousands.

Comment: @TamásV but this is not only a property of the number of photon you put. Because for fock state: $|n+1\rangle$ and $|n\rangle$ will have a 0 overlap (strong distinguishability), whatever the value of $n$ is. So I would say it is a "mix" between the mathematical structure of the state (coherent), and the fact you put a lot of photons in it which makes that the fact of adding or removing one photon not a big change in the end.

Comment: So the point is we have to make sure we end up with something like $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|g\rangle|\alpha\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|e\rangle|\alpha'\rangle$, where $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\alpha'\rangle$ are practically indistinguishable, and then the following approximation will work in practice: $|\psi\rangle\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)|\alpha\rangle$.

Comment: I've heard another idea: what if we shoot individual photons one by one to the atom which is in ground state $|g\rangle$? Will sooner or later one of the photons cause it to jump into state $|e\rangle$? Or will that surely never happen?

Comment: @TamásV about your first question, yes. The state of the atom must remain pure if we want to do perform a (non noisy) rotation. It will what will happen with coherent state having a lot of photons in, but not fock states. About your second question, in the description with J.C hamiltonian we do not really "shoot photons". It is more like we have a cavity. And we can fill it with photons. Then the atom will pass through the cavity and the longer it stays in the longer it interacts with the photons. So in this case it will for sure interact with it. The resulting state depends on how long [...]

Comment: it interacted with the field as given in the Eq in my answer. If you are having a vision in which you send "packet" of photons we are no more in a cavity model but in a waveguide description. In this case I think (but to verify), what would matter would be the length of the photon packet. But basically as soon as the photon meets the atom it will for sure interact. Maybe not enough to make it from $|g\rangle$ to $|e\rangle$ however. But to have the kind of feeling I think you can think about what happens with fock state in cavity (the atom will always interact with photon, the longer, the more

Comment: it interacts and the ending state will always be an entanglement (maybe a "weak" one with coherent states but in practice excepted for very particular time of interaction it always get entangled)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I get it now why Fock states would not work but coherent state does. I can make the photon-shooting question more concrete. Imagine we shoot just 1 photon, that's all. Is there *any* chance that it will make the atom jump from $|g\rangle$ to $|e\rangle$?

Comment: Or rather, from $|g\rangle$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)$? Or you mean it would end up in a similar entanglement like with the Fock state? How sad...

Comment: @TamásV My point was to say that in a cavity model as the one in my answer it doesn't really make sense to say we "shoot" one photon. The cavity should be seen as a reservoir in which we put energy. To put one photon of energy inside means that it is at the lowest energy eigenstate possible. The photon is not really "shot" it is delocalized everywhere inside of the cavity. If you really want to shoot photons you leave this model and you have to go in a waveguide which I know less. However to answer your question I think that even in a waveguide model you will necesseraly get entangled

Comment: Because one thing to get is that it is not only the number of photon that matter but also the time of interaction. So to know the evolution of your atom with a single photon you also have to know what is the spread of this photon to guess for how long it will interact. For some specific time of interaction maybe you won't have any entanglement. So maybe the transformation $|g\rangle \to |e \rangle$ would be possible (no entanglement), but I expect that in general an arbitrary rotation of your atom is not possible (necessary entanglement). I do a bit of analogy with what happens in a cavity

Comment: In the very end, I think you can base on what happens in cavity to get some basic intuitions about light matter interaction. The math gets more complicated when dealing with multimode fields (which corresponds to wave travelling in waveguide), but some of the basic intuition should remain.

Comment: Yes, in summary, one thing I learned by asking this question is that in reality, it's not as easy and clean to create superposition as I imagined reading quantum computing books... there are lots of physical details, and we basically never end up with a perfect pure state. Thanks a lot for the discussion!

Comment: @TamásV you are welcome. So to say if it is easy or not is quite subjective. In superconducting qubits single qubit manipulation is (quite) clean. One of the limitations there is is spontaneous emission which is resulting also from entanglement with a continuum of E.M modes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119238/discussion-between-tamas-v-and-starbuck).

Answer (score 1):

In most quantum mechanical settings there is a clear separation between the system of interest (say a particle or molecule with some kind of internal structure) and a sort of classical or semi-classical background on which the wave mechanics plays out.  Given a system that is somehow prepared in an initial (coherent) state $\psi$, say with quantum numbers $s, t, x$, etc.,  the starting *premise* is often that the system evolves unitarily.  This premise is nontrivial, however.

More generally, the state of a quantum system is described by a *density matrix*, $\hat \rho$, which allows the possibility that the system is entangled with unobserved (or even undiscovered) degrees of freedom that also exhibit quantum correlations.

In this context, the density matrix of a system $A$ is thought of by positing the existence of a sort of dual system $B$ that sort of *completes* system $A$, in the sense that the joint system $AB$ is described perfectly by a pure wave function $\psi_{AB}$ and undergoes unitary dynamics according to some joint Hamiltonian, $H_{AB}$. Given $\psi_{AB}$ and $H_{AB}$, one first introduces a sort of trivial density matrix $\hat\rho_{AB}$ for the $AB$ system, defined as the *outer product* of $\psi_{AB}$ with its hermitian conjugate, $\psi_{AB}^*$: you can think of it as a projection from the Hilbert space of the $AB$ system onto the one-dimensional span of $\psi_{AB}$. Next, one evaluates the *partial trace* of $\hat\rho_{AB}$ by summing over the quantum numbers of the $B$ system.  The result is an object $\hat\rho_A$ that describes the statistics of measuring the $A$ system following an (unknown or forgotten) measurement of the $B$ system.

In the system that you describe, it sounds as though the photon (or electromagnetic field) in question might not be an entirely classical coordinate.  Hence, in order to actually describe the full quantum state, it might be necessary to include an additional quantum number to the state space describing the state of the photon: whether it is absorbed (i.e. 'null') or emitted ('observable'), and perhaps an 'energy' or harmonic index associated with it (unless this is known implicitly: it is analogous in some ways to the pitch of a musical note.)  If you prepared the system/photon ensemble in the completely absorbed state, and allowed it to undergo unitary time evolution according to some appropriate Hamiltonian, you might see the system periodically or quasi-periodically emit and reabsorb the photon (i.e. undergo the transition you describe.)  You might also "observe" the $|g\rangle\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|g\rangle + |e\rangle)$ transition (in a somewhat philosophically convoluted sense) by somehow measuring the state of the photon and triggering a kind of partial wave function collapse of the system, and happening to fall into the $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|g\rangle + |e\rangle)$ branch of reality, or by observing the system in its $|g\rangle$ state at one moment and later somehow choosing a new measurement basis (perhaps via clever interferometry) so that the system's new post-measurement states are $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|g\rangle \pm |e\rangle)$.

Note that it is also possible to produce the transition you describe with a *classical* electromagnetic/photon field, which would simply add a perturbation to the Hamiltonian of the system by itself (without any auxiliary variables or photons.) However, one could not reproduce the full set of quantum mechanically achievable and potentially desirable dynamics of the system plus photon with the system alone.

Comment: Thank you very much. Regarding your last paragraph, do you mean that a perfectly isolated atom in state $|g\rangle$ (without any non-absorbed photon isolated together with it) would never ever transition to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|g\rangle+|e\rangle\right)$, but on the other hand, if the atom starts out in $|e\rangle$, it can transition to any superposition of $|g\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$ by itself, while remaining perfectly isolated? It seems that in the former case $|g\rangle$ is meant without any extra photon, while in the latter with one extra photon that is part of the isolated system.

Comment: Not exactly: a classical external field could also cause the transition, but the density matrix of the atom would always remain 'pure'.  In contrast, in a (quantized) photon + atom system, the density matrix of the atom could undergo a more complicated dynamics, in which it periodically or quasiperiodically decoheres and recoheres.